# Is there any way to get a macro or module to change the copy destination cell from one cell to another cell in the next row with each run?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to use a macro to copy information from a cell on a worksheet to another worksheet.  I would like to be able to copy the value of the cell from the next cell (next row) each time the macro is used. Is this possible?

Thanks.

```
             Sheet 1 (A1) =10001
                     (B1) =15467
                     (C1) =18956
```

Would like to run a macro that opens new sheet (Sheet2) and puts 10001 in B10 on Sheet2.  If I click on Sheet2 and run the macro again, a new sheet (Sheet3) would put 15467 in B10 on Sheet 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you can do it a couple of different ways:

**Method 1**

In your macro, you will need code that counts how many sheets exist in the workbook.  Then use that number to determine what cell on `Sheet1` should be copied to cell `B10` on the new sheet.
This method has some pitfalls if you have other sheets in your workbook.

**Method 2**

Store the row number of the cell you want to copy in a cell somewhere on `Sheet1`.  Every time your macro runs, retrieve that value to determine which cell to copy to the new sheet, then increment that value, so the next time the macro runs, it will get the next cell.
This method is probably the most straight-forward, but you need to make sure that you don't accidentally erase or alter the cell containing your current row number.

Comment: How do you increment the value?  (I am very new to VBA.)  Thanks.

Comment: `Cell(<address>).Value = Cell(<address>).Value +1`